# Logcat doesn't work after root

Tags: android, root, logcat, galaxy

i'm using Android Studio 1.5.1 and my device is Galaxy Note 4 with Andorid 5.1.1.
Until now everything is working correctly, but after rooting the device, the logcat left me working. With all others enabled devices works correctly but with the Galaxy Note 4 does not. I tried on different computers and operating systems, but not working.
Someone happened the same problem?
Any alternatives to make it work properly?
Thank you.

Comment: Have you also tried adb logcat on the terminal ?

Comment: Hello @SaurabhVerma thanks for answer me.
Yes, I tried but nothings show.

Comment: I know, it sounds like a joke, but have you tried to reboot your phone? In general, AFAIK, rooting is not suppose to break logcat feature

Comment: @KonstantinLoginov Yes, I tried to reboot but doesn't work.
I used this post to root my device: http://galaxynote4root.com/galaxy-note-4-root/how-to-root-galaxy-note-4note-edge-on-android-5-1-1/4/

Comment: Also have this problem with Note 4 after root unfortunately. @JaviChaqués did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by removing root and rerooting using N910F-Stock_Kernel_XXU1OH4_Root_Permissive_NTFS_PhilZ_v1.0.zip that can be downloaded from
https://mega.nz/#F!RV8wGT6C!rsfnBrjuqukBNLgLxIgNIA . 
Got this from http://forum.xda-developers.com/note-4/snapdragon-dev/n910f-android-stock-5-1-1-kernel-root-t3208778 . Also cleaned dalvik cache and cache before rooting again (not that it matters). Make sure to backup (at first try I got stuck in bootloop since I accidentally removed /system, but luckily had backup, so restored and tried again and it worked).

Comment: Thank you, i will try this!